In a phrase containing a sequence of "personalizing" / identity forming adjectives that can also be a noun on its own, which one is primary?
I'm talking about a series of words that each can function as an adjective AS WELL AS a noun, such as

ethnic / race words ("Chinese", "Indian", "Scot", "Irish", "Caucasian", "Black")
political words ("Democrat", "Republican", "Whig", "Tory", "American", "Canadian")
religion words ("Christian", "Catholic", "Sikh", "pagan", "atheist")
gender words ("male", "female")
etc.

that one can string together in an identity-description label for a person.  Each of those words imply a "person" and can be used independently as a replacement where the context of a sentence / phrase requires a human being.
For example, if one says

A Liberal Catholic Chinese Canadian gave the commencement speech yesterday.

which word does the English language usage consider as primary in that sentence?  Is it the fact that the person is a Canadian citizen?  Will it be the last word in the sequence, as a default rule, or the order does not matter?  For example, if the word order is modified to

A Canadian Liberal Chinese Catholic gave the commencement speech yesterday.

does it change anything?
Another context would be to answer the implicit question "who are you?" to a man.  If he says

I am a Canadian Liberal Chinese Catholic.

does it imply that being Catholic is the most important part of his identity?
Maybe there is a rule which needs to be adhered to when stringing those words together depending on the KIND of the adjective, thus limiting allowable options and forcing one to rephrase when the last word is not the most important adjective?  For example, the gender words seem to needing to be placed last because this doesn't sound right:

A Canadian Male Liberal Chinese Catholic gave the commencement speech yesterday.


The final term in such constructions is the "head" noun, so if you thought the fact of the speaker being Canadian was contextually more central to his identity than the fact of him being Catholic, you could report it as A Male Liberal Chinese Catholic Canadian gave the commencement speech yesterday. I doubt the "Royal Order of Adjectives" is much use here, but I suppose in principle "most important details first" could be a factor in sequencing all the other "noun adjuncts". But it rapidly becomes hopelessly non-idiomatic with more than one or two anyway, so don't sweat it too much.

There seem to be significantly more published written instances of American female reporters than female American reporters. But I think that just reflects the fact that contextually, it's more likely we'd be specifically focusing on the "American" subset of women reporters, rather than the "female" subset of American reporters. It's the exact context that governs what you might want to emphasize by word order.

Some are nouns, adjectival, only if preceded by the (not a or an), and some shouldn't be used those ways at all, in AmE, just FYI.

This is an interesting question. "Catholic Republicans" and "Republican Catholics" denote the same set of people, but in many contexts there would be a clear preference for one or the other. I'm not sure what the general rules are, though.

It could be that 'Chinese Canadian' is seen as exocentric, which would mean that the term has no independent structure. Thus a guinea pig is neither a guinea nor a pig.

But “Catholic Democrats” and “Democratic Catholics”... @alphabet

There are a lot of ethnonyms like "African American" which have specific meanings not necessarily obvious from the individual words - e.g. "African American" implies a black person of African origin, probably descended from slaves. While "American African" isn't commonly used and I think most people would be a bit stumped by it.

I don't think there's a firm rule, although it's probably natural to put the more fundamental term last, whatever you consider that to be (this is commonly gender or nationality) - similar to how English adjective order works. But which is most important/fundamental is context-dependent.
